# How to perform a column by column circular shift of a matrix without a loop

Tags: matlab

I need to circularly shift individual columns of a matrix.

This is easy if you want to shift all the columns by the same amount, however, in my case I need to shift them all by a different amount.

Currently I'm using a loop and if possible I'd like to remove the loop and use a faster, vector based, approach.

My current code

```
A = randi(2, 4, 2);
B = A;
for i = 1:size( A,2 );
   d = randi( size( A,1 ));
   B(:,i) = circshift( A(:,i), [d, 0] );
end
```

Is is possible to remove the loop from this code?

**Update**  I tested all three methods and compared them to the loop described in this question.  I timed how long it would take to execute a column by column circular shift on a 1000x1000 matrix 100 times. I repeated this test several times.

**Results**:

- My loop took more than 12 seconds
- Pursuit's suggestion less than a seconds
- Zroth's orginal answer took just over 2 seconds
- Ansari's suggest was slower than the original loop

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a loop. If you need it to be fast, you could write your own extension in c.

Comment: I would leave the loop alone.  Matlab is actually pretty good at loops and low level operations.  I would try and remove the call to `circshift`, and replace it with an appropriate indexing operation.  `circshift` contains useful error checking and input parsing which you can probably do without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

Pursuit is right: Using a for-loop and appropriate indexing seems to be the way to go here. Here's one way of doing it:

```
[m, n] = size(A);
D = randi([0, m - 1], [1, n]);
B = zeros(m, n);

for i = (1 : n)
    B(:, i) = [A((m - D(i) + 1 : m), i); A((1 : m - D(i) ), i)];
end
```

### Original answer

I've looked for something similar before, but I never came across a good solution.  A modification of one of the algorithms used [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22858-circulant-matrix/content/circulant.m) gives a slight performance boost in my tests:

```
[m, n] = size(A);
mtxLinearIndices ...
    = bsxfun(@plus, ...
             mod(bsxfun(@minus, (0 : m - 1)', D), m), ...
             (1 : m : m * n));
C = A(idxs);
```

Ugly? Definitely. Like I said, it seems to be slightly faster (2--3 times faster for me); but both algorithms are clocking in at under a second for `m = 3000` and `n = 1000` (on a rather old computer, too).

It might be worth noting that, for me, both algorithms seem to outperform the algorithm provided by Ansari, though his answer is certainly more straightforward. (Ansari's algorithm's output does not agree with the other two algorithms for me; but that could just be a discrepancy in how the shifts are being applied.) In general, `arrayfun` seems pretty slow when I've tried to use it. Cell arrays also seem slow to me. But my testing might be biased somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much faster this would be, but you could try this:

```
[nr, nc] = size(A);
B = arrayfun(@(i) circshift(A(:, i), randi(nr)), 1:nc, 'UniformOutput', false);
B = cell2mat(B);
```

You'll have to benchmark it, but using arrayfun may speed it up a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect, your circular shifting, operations on the random integer matrix donot make it any more random since the numbers are uniformly distributed.

So I hope your question is using randi() for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: My real world application is much more complex then this. When I ask questions I like to boil them down to a simple bare minimum example that describes the problem.

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with the question and it is definitely not ans answer. Also I doubt the answer help OP. I would like to give -100, but since -1 is the most: -1.