# parallel column by column circular shifting in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I am trying to run a beamforming algorithm which requires me to introduce time delays into a matrix (more specifically, I have to sum together time shifted vectors). I was hoping to (approximately) accomplish this by circularly shifting each column by the right amount. Doing this operation once (or similar operations, as answered here: [How to perform a column by column circular shift of a matrix without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584711/how-to-perform-a-column-by-column-circular-shift-of-a-matrix-without-a-loop)) ) don't take much time, but I have to do this tens to hundreds of thousands of times. 
Seeing as each operation is independent of each other, I was hoping I would be able to do them in parallel, possibly on a GPU, however I haven't been able to find any way to do it. I can use a parfor loop to speed things up a little, but not by much.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could do this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have no idea about what beamforming is, but are you aware there is a "Phased Array System Toolbox" in Matlab with several (time delay) [beam forming](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/phased/beamforming.html) algorithms?
I would assume they put some efficient code in this - if it fits your needs. There are also several "beam forming" hits on matlab file exchange...

Comment: Also, it seems you can just push arrays (say x) to the gpu with `gx=gpuArray(x)` and then use that to compute on the gpu. Since basic commands and also circshift are gpu-enabled this should work easily (although i have never tested this). See [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html).

Comment: I have looked into the PAS toolbox, however its upwards of 200$ and I'm just a student, so it's probably out of the question. I'll look further into the beamforming on the file exchange though.

As for just pushing the arrays to the GPU, you can push a whole matrix and calculate a circshift for only one value, ie shift the whole matrix by some constant. What I need is to be able to shift each column by a different amount. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: Did you try to use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11586007/edit) and use gpuArrays with it?

Comment: Are you referring to the solution involving bsxfun? The problem with that solution is that the only part of it that is doable on the GPU is already fast on the CPU. By that I mean calculating the indices (the bsxfun part) is fast on CPU, but the indexing itself (C = A(idx)) is 100x slower on the GPU. So no, as far as I can tell that solution won't work here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "you need to shift each column by a different amount" - can't you just upload each column of your matrix separately or use `circshift(A(:,j),k)` to shift column j by k (and repeat this for all columns)?

Comment: Each column represents a single sensors data, and each sensor has a time lag. So each column needs to be shifted by a different amount. I can use circshift as you suggest, but the point is that I want to be able to all those calculations massively in parallel. A parfor loop can handle this doing 4 at a time (in the case of my computer), but I was hoping to find some way to do many more in parallel. 
I was hoping to be able to use gpuArray to circshift a whole matrix at once using the appropriate lags for each column, but I'm not sure if its possible.